# How to access contents of folder 'nul' windows?

Tags: windows, file-management

I created a folder with the name NUL, which is traditionally not possible without any fancy tricks.

This folder has unusual properties as trying to copy it, rename it or delete it causes problems because of underlying WINDOWS OS architecture limitations.

Now if you try to drag in a file called a.txt, it will absorb the file, but where did it go? piping files to NUL would delete the data, but. If I try to copy another file called a.txt, it will say NUL already contains a file with that name. So the windows file system still has some idea of filenames inside NUL.

I tried renaming NUL back to a normal folder, but couldn't get that to work. I tried whatever I could, but I think it's impossible to get back to the contents.

Does anyone have experience with NUL and other reserved folders and know why you can't perform certain operations on this folder and most importantly, how to get the files back thrown into NUL. Or are these files permanently lost?

Answer (score 1):

I found a way, even though the folder properties and everything tell the user the folder is empty and your contents are lost. You can rename the folder with:

> `C:\> rename \\.\C:\..\NUL. deletefile.txt`

[Deleting/Renaming a file named NUL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17883481/delete-a-file-named-nul-on-windows)

Then as you wish you can delete this as any other textfile with:

> `C:\> del deletefile.txt`